# Separate Number using Masked textbox

Tags: vb.net

I don't know how to work with this, I have this who's input will be a valid sss or tin number (e.g 111-1111-111)

[Example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqrLt.png)

and my code is:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        If TextBox1.Text.Length = 4 Then
            TextBox1.Text &= "-"
            TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.Text.Length, 0)
        ElseIf TextBox1.Text.Length = 11 Then
            TextBox1.Text &= "-"
            TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.Text.Length, 0)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [MaskedTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx) and set the `Mask()` property to `0000-000000-000`.  The dash will be inserted for you as the digits are typed.